# Hashing Pandas dataframe breaks

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, hash

First import:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import hashlib
```

Next, consider the following:

```
np.random.seed(42)
arr = np.random.choice([41, 43, 42], size=(3,3))
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
print(arr)
print(df)
print(hashlib.sha256(arr.tobytes()).hexdigest())
print(hashlib.sha256(df.values.tobytes()).hexdigest())
```

Multiple executions of this snippet yield the same hash twice all the time: `ddfee4572d380bef86d3ebe3cb7bfa7c68b7744f55f67f4e1ca5f6872c2c9ba1`.

However, if we consider the following:

```
np.random.seed(42)
arr = np.random.choice(['foo', 'bar', 42], size=(3,3))
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
print(arr)
print(df)
print(hashlib.sha256(arr.tobytes()).hexdigest())
print(hashlib.sha256(df.values.tobytes()).hexdigest())
```

*Note* that there are strings in the data now. The hash of the `arr` is fixed (`52db9328682317c44370b8186a5c6bae75f2a94c9d0d5b24d61f602857acd3de`) for different evaluations, but the one of the `pandas.DataFrame` changes each time.

Any pythonic way around it? No Pythonic?

Edit: Related links:

- [Hashable DataFrames](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/3882)

Answer (score 2):

A pandas `DataFrame` or `Series` can be hashed using the [`pandas.util.hash_pandas_object`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.util.hash_pandas_object.html) function, starting in version 0.20.1.

Answer (score 0):

According to me when you are using string as values for your cells. Data frame type is object

```
df.dtypes
```

shows that. 
That is why you get different hash each time.

Answer (score 0):

Naive workaround is to get a string representation of the whole dataframe and hash it. In particular either of the following can work:

```
print(hashlib.sha256(df.to_json().encode()).hexdigest())
print(hashlib.sha256(df.to_csv().encode()).hexdigest())
```

Naturally, this is going to be very length for big dataframes.

Still, the it remains that `pd.DataFrame(arr).values != arr`, and this is counter-intuitive.

See a summary: https://gist.github.com/drorata/bfc5d956c4fb928dcc77510a33009691

Comment: [Blog post summary](http://drorata.github.io/posts/2017/May/26/when-trying-to-hash-a-data-frame/)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [package](https://github.com/baowei521/hashable_ndframes) with hashable subclasses of `Series` and `DataFrame` for my needs. Hope this helps.